# move_upload_file not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, upload

Hi so I am trying to upload an image to my db and a folder as well as other elements from my form, is all working great except I can't get the file to appear in the uploads folder. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //This gets all the other information from the form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $founded = $_POST['founded'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $uploaded_dir = "/httpdocs/uploads/";
    $path = $uploaded_dir . $fileName;

    print "Temporary name: " . $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "<br>";
    print "Original name: $filename<br>";
    print "Destination: $path<br>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $path)) {
        print "Uploaded file moved";
        // do something with the file here
    } else {
        print "Move failed";
    }

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    // Connects to your Database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
    mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error()) ;


    //Writes the information to the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, description, founded, category, logo)".
    "VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$founded', '$category', '$fileName')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    include 'library/closedb.php';

    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
```

This is the response I get every time

```
Temporary name: /tmp/phpA8JjRz
Original name:
Destination: /httpdocs/uploads/fixed.png
Move failed
File fixed.png uploaded
```

This is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="path" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Flying School</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="fsn" placeholder="Flying School Name" required/><br />
<label>Category</label><br />
<select name="category">
  <option value="0">one</option>
  <option value="1">two</option>
  <option value="2">three</option>
  <option value="3">four</option>
</select><br />
<label>Founded</label><br />
<input type="text" name="founded" id="founded" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" /><br />
<label>Logo</label><br />
<!--<div class="uploadlogo">-->
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
<!--</div>--><br />
<label>Cover Image</label><br />
<div class="coverimage">
<input type="file" name="cover" id="cover" />
</div><br />
<label>Description</label><br />
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['description'])) $initialentry=$_POST['description'];
  else $initialentry='';
  $editor = JFactory::getEditor();
  echo $editor->display( 'description',  $initialentry, '80%', '350', '55', '20', false  ) ;
?><br />
<label>Photos</label><br />
<ul id="addPhotos">
<li><div class="upload1">
<input type="file" name="acimg1" id="acimg1" />
</div></li>
<li><div class="upload2">
<input type="file" name="acimg2" id="acimg2" />
</div></li>
<li><div class="upload3">
<input type="file" name="acimg3" id="acimg3" />
</div></li>
</ul>
<br />
<label>Choose here</label><br />
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Rss">R22
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="R44">R44
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="R66">R66
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="AS355">AS355
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="PA28">PA28
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="CESSNA172">Cessna 172
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="CESSNA152">Cessna 152
</label><br />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: check folder permissions and the path. error reporting will help you here

Comment: Plus, we've no way to tell if your form is correct or not

Comment: @Fred-ii- ive added the form

Comment: Thanks Dave. It looks ok then. My first comment mentioned to check the folder's permissions if it can be written to, and if the path is correct. Use error reporting also.

Comment: `/httpdocs/uploads/` that should be a full system path. I.e.: `/var/usr/httpdocs/uploads/` or a relative path I.e.: `../uploads/`. I doubt your root is `/httpdocs/`. Use `phpinfo()` to check what the root is.

Comment: the folder is set to 755 and error reporting not sure

Comment: I wrote another comment above yours ^. Let me know about that. I'll delete this comment shortly in order not to tie up the comments section too much. Ping me, I have to leave for 1/2 hour.

Comment: SOLVED!!! thanks man I got the true path for the folder and its worked like a dream!! you my friend are a life saver!

Comment: Some time ago I faced a problem when I was testing a file upload form in a web application I had worked on. Everything was going fine, the record of the file was being correctly written to the database table it should have written to, but the file was not being upload: move_uploaded_file() seemed not to be working if the file was coming from the same server (a.k.a.: it was not an uploaded file). Not sure about your scenario, so I post this as a comment, it might be useful ;)

Comment: @Velnias this is the exact issue i had but thanks to Fred I changed the path to my full path and it worked like a dream

Comment: @Fred-ii- sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: This code is open to SQL injections.

Comment: @DaveLynch Hey Dave, I'm back. I'm glad to hear that it worked out and I've put my comment to an answer below, *cheers*

Comment: @chris85 I have Chris. I was away for a bit and came back to post my answer below, *cheers*.

Comment: @DaveLynch *"SOLVED!!! thanks man I got the true path for the folder and its worked like a dream!! you my friend are a life saver!"* - You're most welcome Dave.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a permissions issue. Check ownership of your script and make sure it's not owned by root, choown it to apache:apache. Also make sure the folder you're writing the file to is writable - 755 permission level.

Comment: @DaveLynch you realize the question is still considered as open/unsolved. I posted my answer on Jun 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"SOLVED!!! thanks man I got the true path for the folder and its worked like a dream!! you my friend are a life saver! – Dave Lynch"*

Putting my comment to an answer:

`/httpdocs/uploads/` that should be a full system path.

I.e.: `/var/usr/httpdocs/uploads/` or a relative path. I.e.: `../uploads/`.

I doubt your root is `/httpdocs/`. System paths usually start by `/var/usr/` on most servers. Others have something like `/var/usr/public_html/` etc. There are more, but these are enough examples.

Using `phpinfo()` will show you what your system path is.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Also as stated in comments:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: Check the **administrator permission** for the path you have selected to move your uploaded file

Secondly: Check the **root** folder if it exist in directory `path/` else you would not be able to move uploaded file. try `../dirname` to **back** and **change** your `dir`